# Ĉu la tabelvorto "ĉies" signifas "de ĉiu" aŭ "de ĉiuj"?

Tags: correlatives

Mi iam devis lerni la diferencon inter ĉiu kaj ĉiuj. Nun mi havas pluan demandon. Ĉu la vorto "ĉies" signifas "de ĉiu" aŭ "de ĉiuj"? Ĉu oni uzu la pluralon post ĝi aŭ ne?

> Ĉies patrino meritas brakumon hodiaŭ.
>
> Ĉies patrinoj meritas brakumojn hodiaŭ.

Answer (score 7):

Ambaŭ estas ĝustaj, kaj la poseda rilato povas preni iun ajn formon: de unu al unu, de unu al pluraj, de pluraj al unu, de pluraj al pluraj, ktp.

- *Ĉies patrino ricevos cent dolarojn. (= la patrino de ĉiu)*
- *Ĉi tiu mondo estas ĉies mondo. (= la mondo de ĉiuj)*
- *Ĉies gepatroj ricevos cent dolarojn. (= la gepatroj de ĉiu)*
- *Ĉi tiuj libroj en la librejo estas ĉies libroj. (= la libroj de ĉiuj)*

En via ekzemplo, la elekto dependas de la dezirata emfazo: persona dankemo al ĉiu individua patrino, aŭ dankemo al patrinoj ĝenerale.